# boost::transform_iterator in std::upper_bound compile error

Tags: c++, boost, iterator

I have a list of nodes sorted by z-order (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order_curve).
I am trying to find the first node bigger than zPosition.
The iterTransform object takes an iterator and returns a binary position representation (same type as zPosition). This type can be compared by pathCmp

```
NodeIterT last = std::upper_bound(
    boost::make_transform_iterator(begin, iterTransform), // return PathType
    boost::make_transform_iterator(end, iterTransform),
    zPosition,
    pathCmp ); // takes two PathType arguments
```

when compiling this I get

error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'boost::transform_iterator < UnaryFunc,Iterator,Reference,Value > ' to 'std::_Vector_iterator<_Myvec>'

Is there any mistake in this minimized example or do I need to provide more code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::upper_bound` returns a `transform_iterator`. Add `.base()` to get the iterator type that you wrapped:

```
NodeIterT last = std::upper_bound(
boost::make_transform_iterator(begin, iterTransform), // return PathType
boost::make_transform_iterator(end, iterTransform),
zPosition,
pathCmp ).base();
```

should work assuming `begin` and `end` are of `NodeIterT` type.

Answer (score 2):

`std::upper_bound` returns an iterator with the same type as those given as parameters. In your case, the return type is therefore `boost::transform_iterator<...>` and not `std::vector<...>::iterator`.

If you want to access the underlying iterator, you can use the [`base()` member function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/iterator/doc/transform_iterator.html):

```
NodeIterT last = std::upper_bound(
    boost::make_transform_iterator(begin, iterTransform), // return PathType
    boost::make_transform_iterator(end, iterTransform),
    zPosition,
    pathCmp ).base(); // note the call to base()
```